# Allegory behind Rebirth of life

Tags: buddhism

Buddha says the ultimate goal of man is Nirvana or to escape the cycle of rebirth.

By this does he really means the physical rebirth of life or there is some allegory?

For me apparently it seems he is talking about the mental rebirth of one's life.Like everyday saying themselves that they will change the way they perform actions but at the end of the day guilt prevails and they push it for next forming sort of viscous cycle!
So by this buddha might wants us to escape this viscous cycle and attain a constant state of mental commitment or doing the things as we want independent of control by senses and free will.

Comment: 'Ultimate goal': Buddhism is about the path to the cessation of suffering, how you value that is up to you. What are you asking here, is rebirth a metaphor? Rebirth has to be squared with [anatta] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatt%C4%81), so you might say rebirth happens but no permanent self is reborn. Non-clinging, non-desiring, are part of this - not simply steadiness of goals, but a reorientation of life to situate beyond having goals. See [Does Buddhism espouse reincarnation?] (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77815/does-buddhism-espouse-reincarnation/77825#77825)

Answer (score 2):

The historical Buddha understands the cycle of rebirth as a consequence of karma. A key passage of his teaching is in the Pali canon: Anguttara Nikaya, Book II, Sutta 232, for example cf. p. 601 from

http://lirs.ru/lib/sutra/The_Numerical_Discourses_of_the_Buddha,Anguttara_Nikaya,Bodhi,2012.pdf

Here Buddha teaches the consequences of the four different types of karma. Each type of karma causes rebirth in a corresponding world. It is apparent from the text that Buddha refers to a **physical rebirth**. He does not refer to a daily new start with new purposes.

Nevertheless, you indicate a crucial point of the whole Nirvana-enterprise: The mental and behavioral orientation according to the **8-fold path**. That's a task to start new on each day.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of the historical Buddha, there is reason to believe that in the northern part of the Indian subcontinent, it was a widely-held view that all beings are subject to a cycle of birth, death, and rebirth that only comes to an end once some form of spiritual liberation has been achieved. Both the classical Hindu and Jain religious traditions have an analogue of the Buddhist idea of *nibbāna*, and all three treat it as the ultimate end of human life. However, Buddhist, Hindu, and Jain scholars would offer rather distinct explanations of how the cycle of birth, death, and rebirth occurs in practice, and how one ought to understand what it means to be liberated from suffering.

In the *Ariyapariyesana Sutta* in the Pali Canon, the Buddha describes the period of his life when he “went forth from the home life into homelessness, seeking the supreme state of sublime peace.” Of course, this “state of sublime peace” is a reference to *nibbāna*, which he describes at length in the discourse as “supreme security from bondage” that is

> unborn, unaging, unailing, sorrowless, and deathless.

A theme of the Pali Canon that is repeated time and again is that all that is subject to birth, aging, and death is inevitably intertwined with suffering (*duhkha*). Indeed this is made explicit in the *Ariyapariyesana Sutta*. Hence one presumably needs to escape rebirth altogether if one’s suffering is to be completely extinguished. Confusingly, however, the discourse ends with a description of the moment at which the Buddha “attained supreme security from bondage, nibbāna,” and he was obviously still alive at this point. He concludes by exclaiming “My liberation is unshakable. This is my last birth. Now there is no more renewed existence.” This suggests to me that the cessation of rebirth is essential to the notion of nibbāna.

Comment: Could you please add one of your favorite references from the Pali canon to document that the historical Buddha did consider nirvana as the end of physical rebirths. Because the OP asks whether Buddha instead could have referred to a daily mental new-orientation.

Comment: @JoWehler Oops, I was so focused on trying to give a non-dogmatic, balanced presentation of the various religions' views on rebirth that I inadvertently failed to answer the OP's question. I will edit my reply accordingly, and I thank you for your feedback.